# Put time into cell

Tags: google-sheets

In Google spreadsheet I would like to put the time `HH:mm` in a cell `A2` if the cell `A2` is empty and if another cell `A1` has a value greater than zero.

It's possible?

Now I have in `A2 =If(A1>0;NOW();"")` but `A2` is always changing

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround but in practice may be more convenient than alternatives that may require a script. Please try adjusting your formula to:

```
=if(A1>0;B1;"")
```

where B1 is any convenient cell. Then selecting that cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>;</kbd>. This should put the current time in B1 (or wherever) but unlike =NOW() it does not update.

Strictly speaking this does not comply with *I would like to put the time HH:mm in a cell A2 if the cell A2 is empty* - because A2 is the location of the formula, but I hope that is not an issue for you.